# How to scroll with mouse wheel and keyboard on vertical slider in echarts?

Tags: reactjs, charts, frontend, data-visualization, echarts

I need to scroll an echart component vertically with mouse wheel and keyboard. I have tried the datazoom configurations `moveOnMouseWheel` and `moveOnMouseWheel` but **that only zooms** the chart. i don't want it to zoom. the vertical scrollbar should move up and down with mouse and keyboard.

demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/echarts-twb1u?file=/src/datepicker.js:970-995

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the **slider** `zoomLock: true` and the following options for the **inside** zoom:

```
zoomOnMouseWheel: false,
moveOnMouseMove: true,
moveOnMouseWheel: true
```

If you look at the [Gantt example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=custom-gantt-flight), you'll see these settings as such:

```
{
    type: 'slider',
    yAxisIndex: 0,
    zoomLock: true,
    width: 10,
    right: 10,
    top: 70,
    bottom: 20,
    start: 95,
    end: 100,
    handleSize: 0,
    showDetail: false,
}, {
    type: 'inside',
    id: 'insideY',
    yAxisIndex: 0,
    start: 95,
    end: 100,
    zoomOnMouseWheel: false,
    moveOnMouseMove: true,
    moveOnMouseWheel: true
}
```

Comment: Could you help me - how to enable scrolling over the left part of the table? In your linked example (https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=custom-gantt-flight), scrolling over the left part is also not enabled.